# Unable to save the edited comment

Tags: bug, comments, edits

I wasn't able to save the edits to my comments posted on Stack Exchange within the set rules for edits (should be within 5 minutes of creation, and should not have more than one edit in 5 sec). The error message displayed was that I was saving an edit within 5 sec which is not allowed. I took the following video https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz7cfjn56iz6o7f/Editing_comment_doesnt_work.swf?dl=0 which led to a wrong conclusion that the add-ons in the chrome browser might be responsible for the behavior. I have tested the scenario after disabling the add-ons on chrome, and also tested on FireFox. Both showed the same behavior.

After this I have suspected a network issue, so tested on a different network where rest of the conditions are the same. I am not able to reproduce the issue on the second network https://www.dropbox.com/s/fga7ot632t822av/2016-12-27_2154_Able_to_edit_comment.swf?dl=0. The first network was a corporate network, and the second was a home network. As this issue basically is not a Stack Exchange issue, this can be closed. But, it should be noted that this is definitely a network issue and I don't know what kind of network restriction can restrict that particular behavior.

To confirm this conclusion without doubt, I will test on another machine on the corporate network and report the results. At this point, I believe that I don't need any support on this issue.

OS: Windows 10 Professionanl
Browser 1: Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m
Browser 2: FireFox Version 50.1.0
Antivirus: Windows Defender (Corporate laptop), Avira Antivir (Home laptop)

Comment: Testing the editing with this comment. [status-norepro]

Comment: @Mithrandir, did the question get a -1 because of you? I just posted a video in my comments. I am new to the number system, but I don't think I deserve a -1 on this. You can check the video.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz7cfjn56iz6o7f/Editing_comment_doesnt_work.swf?dl=0

Comment: I am sorry, but I wonder why the negative vote? The criteria for the negative vote is shown as "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". You can see my comments to both the answers provided below, and see the time I put in to resolve this. This is one way to discourage people from reporting anything.

Comment: Some might think it is a no repro, some might think it is not worth fixing. That can explain the down vote. For some reason my system block the download/showing of that video you linked to.

Comment: I will post it on google drive and share soon. It might be after a couple of hours though.

Comment: That spinning wheel inside the textarea means you're infected with some malware. That's not SE responsibility. Clean your computer, and you'll be able to edit comments again.

Comment: I explained in the comments to the next answer that it is an add-on of the browser. I have also said that I disabled the add-on there and also tested in FireFox where there are no add-ons. I can test on a different computer as well and post the results. But, I think whoever is judging the question is not looking at the comments posted on the answers.

Comment: Important information should be inside the post, not comments.

Comment: I will edit the post from now on whenever more information is available. Thanks @Shadow Wizard

Comment: Testing the edit comment on a different network and machine altogether. I was able to edit this comment. I will update the question above with this information. This could be a network issue as the other machine was on a corporate network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the 5-minute period of your comment is allowed to be edited, you can only save your edits after 5 seconds from each other. That means you have to wait 5 seconds after each applied edit to apply another edit to your comment. No bug here, just [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

You might have a userscript or add-on that's causing this. The green circle in the bottom right corner shouldn't be there normally and wherever that came from may be the cause of your problem:

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question with more information. Could you, please take a look one more time.

Comment: By definition, over 10 seconds is a bug... that's weird

Comment: In that case, I would like to report the bug. I can take a video and post it wherever I have to report. If you have the information, could you, please let me know where I can post it.

Comment: This is the place. What we're saying is that the bug should not exist at all

Comment: OK then, I will take a video of editing this comment if I can reproduce it, and provide you with a link.

Comment: I wasn't able to edit the comment I made above. I have recorded the video, but it is in swf format. One of the latest browsers should be able to play it. Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz7cfjn56iz6o7f/Editing_comment_doesnt_work.swf?dl=0.

Comment: Do you have an add-on or userscript? The green thing in the comment box isn't natural

Comment: That is the Grammarly Add-on. I can disable it and try again.

Comment: I disabled Grammarly as well as all other add-ons. I still have the same issue. I can try on other browsers to see if that works.

Comment: Didn't work in FireFox either.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. You cannot edit a comment, and edit it *again* in the next five seconds. The five *minute* window means that after posting the comment, you can only edit it within this period.

Comment: Apparently, smart minds think alike :)

Comment: In that case, I have waited for more than 5 sec to save my edit, and I still got the same message. Basically, I was not able to submit my edited comment. Shouldn't this be a bug? I was on Chrome browser on Windows 10.

Comment: Use a timer to see if it really was 5 seconds

Comment: I definitely did wait for more than 5 seconds :-). But, I will take up your suggestion and will try again to edit this comment assuming the implementation here is the same as on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Tried here to enter "Testing Edit" text at the end of my previous comment. I waited for 10 seconds, but I got the same message again, and could not save my edits.